# What does **{'xerr':cv_std} mean?

Tags: python-3.x

Given the following code

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.barplot(x="CrossValMeans",y="Algorithm",data = cv_res, palette="Set3",**{'xerr':cv_std})
```

What does `**{'xerr':cv_std}` mean?

Answer (score 0):

**{} means you are passing `keyword argument` to a function or a method.

[*args and **kwargs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html) You can check this for better explanation.

As example of

```
class Test:
    def test(self, x, y='y_value', **kwargs):
        print(x, y, kwargs, type(kwargs))

t = Test()
t.test('x_value', **{'a': 1, 'b': 'Hello World'}) # YOU CAN PASS THIS AS **{}
t.test('x_value', a=1, b='Hello World') # OR AS THIS
```

Output:

```
x_value y_value {'a': 1, 'b': 'Hello World'} <class 'dict'>
x_value y_value {'a': 1, 'b': 'Hello World'} <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: That should be `keyword argument` (not keyboard)!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start off by actually explaining what `*` and `**` mean in python. - This is referred to as `unpacking` in Python.

If we take your dict as an example:

```
**{'xerr':cv_std}
```

You're essentially telling python to unpack the values into keyworded arguments; whilst you can change that to:

```
*{'xerr': cv_std}
```

and that will instruct python to pick up the keys and pass them as arguments (not keyworded arguments).

In summary if you look at:

```
def my_function(*args, x, **kwargs):
    print(args, x, kwargs)

my_function(*{'xer': 1}, **{'x': 2})
```

will output:

```
('xer',) 2 {}
```

Unpacking can go a long way beyond unpacking a dict into keyworded arguments or into a tuple of keys.

```
>>> a, *extras = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a
1
>>> extras
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The above is referred to as extended sequence unpacking. There's a whole lot of information that one can discuss about unpacking; I suggest you read online articles for more information.